# Is there a way to unlock the container-form size (especially with child-forms) in QGIS

Tags: qgis

When using complex drag and drop forms in QGIS with containers and sub-containers with relations (parent-form, child-form and child-child-form) the container-size seems to be limited.
There are visibility issues within child- or child-child forms-/containers (red arrow) as a result.

It found no way to modify the height of the containers (orange line below) manually. I only can modify the height of the whole form (green line below) but there is no effect to the container-height.
(I can not use ui-based forms as a workaround, because the project will be used in QFIELD too, which prevents using ui-forms)

[image: example of form height issues]

(With settings in "Layer-Properties | Attibutes Form | DragAndDrop-Designer | Container | Size | Vertical stretch" I have no control to the form size in the expected way)

Does anyone know how to adjust the height of containes (and sub-containers) or do I have to open a feature-request / bug report in QGIS ?

Comment: Bug is reported within https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/55817